# Size of hidden .vs folder

Tags: visual-studio

I use Visual Studio 2017 and in my projects I've noticed a hidden file .vs that takes up around 90% of the project space. 
I've been wondering if I can delete this file and what are the consequences of doing so, as I've been running low on space.

Comment: Tends to be a problem in C++, the intellisense database is stored there and it is usually quite large.  You'll strongly favor Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced, Fallback Location settings.  True, True and, say, c:\temp.  Cleaning up these large files is now very simple.  Deleting the .db files by hand is not an issue, they get rebuilt the next time you open the project.

Comment: You can, but it will just get rebuilt. However, why are you worried about this? Disk space is cheap. If it's a source control thing, you should add it to your `ignore` file.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you elaborate on "Fallback Location"? What is Fallback Location and what directory should I set for it? Guessing from your comment, it seems that a .db file will be created in that folder(Fallback Location) and it's okay to delete the .db file, right?